# example of monotonic nonlinear trend

Tags: statistics

Can anyone give me a clear example of what a "monotonic nonlinear trend" is?  I am trying to teach myself time series analysis and ran across this phrase.  I know what a nonlinear trend looks like but what is a monotonous one?  How does it differ from a non-monotonous nonlinear trend?

Answer (score 1):

A monotone trend would be one that is either increasing, like this: 
[image: increasing]

or decreasing, like this: 
[image: decreasing]

The trend below is *not* monotone. 
[image: not monotone]

Comment: What software did you use to make these?

Comment: @Eric I graphed these functions in Maple 16; they are combinations of polynomial and trig functions picked for illustrative value.